# Can't select custom AWS options group for SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to restore a SQL Server Database from .bak file uploaded on AWS S3

I have created an Options Group with SQLSERVER_BACKUP_RESTORE

[image]

But i can't select it when im creating db instance.

[image]

Any idea ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is lacking details. Could you please Edit the question and add details, such as what steps you are performing (are they in the console or via the AWS CLI?), what you mean by "can't select it" and possibly include a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database and options group configuration problem, the db instance and options group should have same info:

Engine: SQL Server Express Edition
Version: 14